# how to use isChecked in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

so simple issue, I can't figure out the errors I keep getting at the end of my code

it is a simple app that runs like a kids game where a picture is presented and 3 options to select from the code was working fine when I was using an onclicklistener on each radio group to check the answer but now I want to have the checks done on the "check" button that I made and am using the "isPressed" method in android studio and now I'm getting errors about my code

here is the code

```
package com.example.hamdanali.imageview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Random;

public class imagegame extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView pic ;
Button    btn1;
Button    btn2;
Button    btn3;
Button    check;
EditText score;

int array[]={
        R.drawable.one  ,
        R.drawable.two  ,
        R.drawable.three,
        R.drawable.four ,
        R.drawable.five ,
        R.drawable.six  , };

String picname[]={

        "One"  ,
        "Two"  ,
        "Three",
        "Four" ,
        "Five" ,
        "Six"  };
int correctanswer=69;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_imagegame);

    pic =   findViewById(R.id.Pic) ;
    btn1=   findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
    btn2=   findViewById(R.id.Btn2);
    btn3=   findViewById(R.id.Btn3);
    check=  findViewById(R.id.Check);
    score=  findViewById(R.id.SCOREE);

    int randomepicutre = (int) (Math.random()*array.length);
    pic.setImageResource(array[randomepicutre]);

   int randomebuttonposition = (int) (Math.random()*3);
   switch (randomebuttonposition) {
       case 0:
           btn1.setText(picname[randomepicutre]);
           btn2.setText(picname[(randomepicutre + 1) % 3]);
           btn3.setText(picname[(randomepicutre + 2) % 3]);
           correctanswer = 1;
           break;
       case 1:
           btn2.setText(picname[randomepicutre]);
           btn1.setText(picname[(randomepicutre + 1) % 3]);
           btn3.setText(picname[(randomepicutre + 2) % 3]);
           correctanswer = 2;
           break;
       case 2:
           btn3.setText(picname[randomepicutre]);
           btn2.setText(picname[(randomepicutre + 1) % 3]);
           btn1.setText(picname[(randomepicutre + 2) % 3]);
           correctanswer = 3;
           break;
   }

   check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           int randomepicutre = (int) (Math.random() * array.length);
           pic.setImageResource(array[randomepicutre]);
           score.setText(" ");

           if (btn1.isPressed()) { //instead of isPressed try to use isChecked

               if (correctanswer == 1)
                   score.setText("correct answer");
               else {
                   score.setText("try again");
               }
           }
           if (btn2.isPressed()) {//instead of isPressed try to use isChecked
               if (correctanswer == 2)
                   score.setText("correct answer");
               else {
                   score.setText("try again");
               }
           }
           if (btn3.isPressed()) {
               if (correctanswer == 3)
                   score.setText("correct answer");
               else {
                   score.setText("try again");
               }
           }

           int randomebuttonposition = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
           switch (randomebuttonposition) {
               case 0:
                   btn1.setText(picname[randomepicutre]);
                   btn2.setText(picname[(randomepicutre + 1) % 3]);
                   btn3.setText(picname[(randomepicutre + 2) % 3]);
                   correctanswer = 1;
                   break;
               case 1:
                   btn2.setText(picname[randomepicutre]);
                   btn1.setText(picname[(randomepicutre + 1) % 3]);
                   btn3.setText(picname[(randomepicutre + 2) % 3]);
                   correctanswer = 2;
                   break;
               case 2:
                   btn3.setText(picname[randomepicutre]);
                   btn2.setText(picname[(randomepicutre + 1) % 3]);
                   btn1.setText(picname[(randomepicutre + 2) % 3]);
                   correctanswer = 3;
                   break;

           }
       }



     // under this line is where I keep getting the error

     }})})}
```

I'm sorry if my code is messy I just started learning android studio 
any modifications to make my code cleaner would be appriciated

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error log.

Comment: i can only find the entire log which is quite long, is that the one you are asking for

Answer (score 1):

Click Code -> Reformat code and you'll see what's wrong

How it should be:

```
            // under this line is where I keep getting the error
        });
    }
}
```

Why:
You have too much unneeded braces. After the line with error comment you have onClickListener ended. You should close it. As it creates anonymous class (`check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`), you should close anonymous class and method call, hence `});`. If we omit inner part of listener it will look like this.

```
check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... });
```

Then you should close `onCreate()`, then activity class body.

```
            // under this line is where I keep getting the error
        }); // check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    }       // onCreate() {
}           // public class imagegame extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Comment: so this works but could you please explain why does it work or how did you find the issue for future reference (reformatting the code showed no issues )

Comment: Updated the answer